# Range of dates in a django model and admin

Tags: django, django-models, calendar, django-admin

I would like to register a range of dates in the model and have in admin a widget similar to this?
[image]

It's possible to use DateTimeField or calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are part of the ModelForm not the model. You could add a range of dates in the Meta class widget definition like this:

```
class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
                'birthdate': SelectDateWidget(attrs = {
                 },years = range(1920, 2017),),
             }
```